# How to use use destructuring in the same variable multiple times

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, destructuring

I have an old code with several if statements, and on each one of them i need to get the HTTP status code. Something like this:

```
if (x == 1) {
  const { statusCode } = await request(httpUrl...)
  ...
}
else if (x == 2) {
  const { statusCode } = await request (aDifferentHttpUrl...)
  ...
}
// and other if's
```

And i wanted to refactor it into a switch-case statement to be more readable for future me and other people too. But then i realized i cant "const { statusCode }" multiple times like I would do inside multiple if statements, and I can't move the const declaration to outside of the switch-case because the URL changes depending on the value of x.

Is there a correct way to use destructuring of the same variable that i'm not aware of?
Important to note that I'm relatively new to javascript

I tried just copy-pasting the code inside each if to its correspondent case in switch. I wanted to do something like:

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    { statusCode } = await request(http)
    ...
    break
  
  case 2:
    { statusCode } = await request(anotherHttp)
    ...
    break
  
  case ...
}
```

So i don't need to declare the whole response object for each case

Edit: code typos

Comment: why not collect all parameters of request in switch statement or in an object with keys and call request only once at the end?

Comment: Don't use `const`. Just declare it with `let statusCode;` before the `switch` and your destructuring assignments will work.

Comment: @NinaScholz because both the request URL and what i need to do with it changes depending on the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the cases inside a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) to have a local scope for each case.

```js
switch (expression) {
  case 1: {
    const { statusCode } = await request(http)
    /* ... */
  }
  break

  case 2: {
    const { statusCode } = await request(anotherHttp)
    /* ... */
  }
  break

  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ended up being the best solution, thanks.